# ODataRoutePrefix not working for 3rd level

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

When I try to use a third level segment with `[ODataRoutePrefix]` attribute it throws an error like this:

*The path template '[TEMPLATE]' on the action 'Get' in controller 'CONTROLLER-NAME' is not a valid OData path template. Found an unresolved path segment '[LAST-SEGMENT]' in the OData path template '[TEMPLATE]'.*

#### Details

- **ODataRoutePrefix for the parent segment that works**:
  `[ODataRoutePrefix("lawsuits/{parentId}/depositsGuarantees")]`
- **ODataRoutePrefix for the new controller that DOES NOT work**: 
  `[ODataRoutePrefix("lawsuits/{parentId}/depositsGuarantees/{subResourceId}/customFields")]`
- **Error message when starting up the API (`config.EnsureInitialized()`):** 
  *The path template 'lawsuits/{parentId}/depositsGuarantees/{subResourceId}/customFields' on the action 'Get' in controller 'LawsuitDepositGuaranteeCustomFields' is not a valid OData path template. Found an unresolved path segment 'customFields' in the OData path template 'lawsuits/{parentId}/depositsGuarantees/{subResourceId}/customFields'.*

#### Additional info

- The action methods properly expect the parameters defined in the Route prefix. Example:

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Get(int parentId, int subResourceId)
{
    // [...]
}
```

- Although it complained that "Found an unresolved path segment 'customFields'", the same segment works for other existing controllers with the prefix like the following: `[ODataRoutePrefix("lawsuits/{parentId}/customFields")]`, which means there's a model registered on OData for the "customFields" segment.

#### Assemblies affected

OData WebApi lib 6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what was the problem...

The *model* for the `depositsGuarantees` segment was missing a collection property of the *model* registered for the `customFields` segment. In practice this property was missing :

```cs
public IEnumerable<CustomFieldModel> CustomFields { get; set; }
```

I still wonder if I should really use `lawsuits/{parentId}/depositsGuarantees/{subResourceId}/customFields` or just `depositsGuarantees/{parentId}/customFields` (even though `depositsGuarantees` is also a sub-resource), but this is more a conceptual discussion.